# You have requested a non-existent service "file.uploader" - Symfony3

Tags: php

I just created a new service in symfony :

```
// AppBundle\Services\FileUploader.php

<?php

namespace AppBundle\Services;

class FileUploader {
    private $imagesDir;
    private $videosDir;

    public function __construct($imagesDir, $videosDir) {
        $this->imagesDir = $imagesDir;
        $this->videosDir = $videosDir;
    }

    public function upload($form) {
    ///...
    ///...
        }
        return $form;
    }
}
```

I also added the following in my services.yml file :

```
// app\config\services.yml

file.uploader:
    class: AppBundle\Services\FileUploader
    arguments:
        - '%images_directory%'
        - '%videos_directory%'
```

But then, when I try calling it from my controller by using :

```
$uploadModel = $this->get('file.uploader');
```

I get the following error :

> You have requested a non-existent service "file.uploader".

Even though I have specified my arguments in config.yml and by running

```
php bin/console debug:container file.upload --show-arguments
```

I get :

```
Service ID       file.upload
Class            AppBundle\Services\FileUploader
```

Any idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should mark the service as `public`:

```
file.uploader:
    class: AppBundle\Services\FileUploader
    public: true
    arguments:
        - '%images_directory%'
        - '%videos_directory%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Services are normally kept in cache. 
Have you tried cleaning it?

```
php app/console cache:clear --env=prod
php app/console cache:clear --env=dev
```

Comment: Do you have xdebug set up? I think that would be the quickest way to solve this problem. Just follow a code execution and see why it can't find a service.

Comment: I'll definitely check it out for the next time, thanks.